# Python dictionaries and nltk

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm supposed to find the words that show up with multiple POS tags in the brown_news corpus only using python dictionaries. So far, I was only able to get to here:

```
import nltk

brown_news = nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_words(categories="news")

multi_tags = {}

for (word,tag) in brown_news:

. . .
```

I know that you need to put all the word, tags into the dictionary (in this case multi_tags) with an if-then-statement. Would you then use another to sort out the words that don't occur with more than one tag? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me understand better your issue. Do you want only multi-tag words? Words with only one tag you can separate in another list or dictionary?

Comment: I'm look for words in the brown corpus that show up with multiple POS tags.For example ('better', ADV then sometime later you notice 'better', NN). I'm trying to figure out a way to put those in a dictionary. There is an way to go around it using the FreqDist and Contributions functions but I'm restricted to just using dictionaries

Comment: Can you use lists in your dictionary? For instance: {'better':['ADV','NN']}.

Comment: As long as it is the dictionary and not a list of the word,tag pairs in brackets. I'm supposed to fill the dictionary with the pairs and them run through them with an if, than statement to see if they show up multiple times in the brown_news corpus but with different tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `defaultdict` to keep track of the word-POS occurence. Hope this helps:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> word2pos = defaultdict(set)
>>> for i in brown.tagged_words():
...     word2pos[i[0]].add(i[1])
... 
>>> for word in word2pos:
...     if len(word2pos[word]) > 1:
...             print word, word2pos[word]
```

[out]:

```
consented set(['VBN', 'VBD'])
centered set(['VBN', 'VBD'])
conspicuously set(['QL', 'RB'])
injected set(['VBN', 'VBD'])
strung set(['VBN', 'VBD'])
ram set(['VB', 'NN'])
relatively set(['QL', 'RB'])
postgraduate set(['JJ', 'NN'])
rides set(['VBZ', 'NNS'])
glimpsed set(['VBN', 'VBD'])
Ogden set(['NP', 'NP-HL', 'NP-TL'])
Reports set(['VBZ', 'NNS', 'NNS-TL'])
audition set(['VB', 'NN'])
commanding set(['VBG', 'NN'])
glow set(['VB', 'VB-HL', 'NN'])
metal set(['NN-HL', 'NN'])
contacted set(['VBN', 'VBD'])
```